# Data in <input> and make covert input*s val() to object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, object, input

**HTML :**

```
<textarea>
http://ex.com=>sitename1=>Fashion
http://some.com=>sitename2=>Sport
</textarea>
<br>
<code></code>
```

**jQuery :**

```
val = $("textarea").text();
obj = val.substr(val.indexOf ( '=>' ) )

$("code").html(obj)
```

i dont have any idea...

Test here : http://jsfiddle.net/2heTu/

**Any way can i get result and use objects like :**

1. ex.com (sitename1 in Fashion category)
2. some.com (sitename2 in Sport category)
3. ..... more more more

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking. Can you please try to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry for bad english, just use textarea to save some data and use this

Comment: No, it's not your english. I just couldn't figure out what you want to do with the textarea's contents after getting it.

Comment: to use like database like val(), like object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var val = $("textarea").text(),
    parts = val.split(/[\r\n]+/);
$.each(parts, function(i, val) {
    if(val.length) {
        var temp = $.trim(val).split('=>'),
            output = '';

        output += temp[0].replace('http://', '') + '(' + temp[1] + ' in ' + temp[2] + ' category)';
    $("code").append(output).append('<br>');
}
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2heTu/7/)**

#### Note

- to get value of textarea `.val()` method used
- `.split(/[\r\n]+/)`  used to get each lines
- `$.each(parts, function(i, val) {..}` make loop over each lines
  where

  - `i` arguments is the index `0,1,2..`
  - `val` holds each lines
- `if(val.length) {..` check for empty value
- `$.trim(val)` remove spaces
- `$.trim(val).split('=>')` split each line with `=>` and return an array like 
  `temp = ["http://ex.com", "sitename1", "Fashion"]` and so on
  and

  - `temp[0]` contains url
  - `temp[1]` contains sitename
  - `temp[2]` contains category
- `` `temp[0].replace('http://', '') `` remove `http://` from url
- `$("code").append(output)` append the output to
- `.append('<br>')` add new line after each output

Comment: lastest is undefined :( can i cut this ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you most of the way there:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var val = $("textarea").val(); // You'll want a more targetd selector there, not just "textarea"
  var lines = val.split(/[\r\n]+/);

  $.each(lines, function(index, line) {
    var parts = line.split(/ *=> */);
    display(parts[0] + " in " + parts[1] + " category " + parts[2]);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ezukec) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ezukec/edit)

What that does:

- `$("textarea").val()` - Gets the value of the first `textarea` on the page. You'll probably want a more targeted selector than that.
- `var lines = val.split(/[\r\n]+/);` - Splits it into lines
- `$.each(lines, function(index, line) { ... });` - Loops over the lines
- `var parts = line.split(/ *=> */);` - Splits the line into individual parts.
- `display(...)` - Displays the parts, but more to the point:

  - `part[0]` the first of the three things on each line (looks like a URL)
  - `part[1]` the second thing (site name?)
  - `part[2]` the third thing (category)

Comment: what about last line ? undefined

Comment: Ah, I should have added a defensive check on that. But really, that's a minor detail.